# Ubuntu 16.04 - sudo apt-get update error

Tags: apt, software-sources

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
$
```

Comment: What is the error, and what is your question?

Comment: @Jos I think he's only hitting 2 PPAs instead of the Ubuntu Sources as well.

Comment: What is the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? There must be an error in there.

Comment: -bash: /etc/apt/sources.lis: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you accidentally delete the file? Or rename it?

Comment: can't see any solution asked for any problem, all seems to be correct

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, you need to edit or create your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now, copy and paste the following contents into the terminal:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Studio 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Alpha amd64 (20151225)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

When that is done, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And to *apply* any updates, run one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```