# multiple errors when run apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, package-management

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

on Ubuntu 16.04 , I got the following

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Error!
W: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/selmf/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3F3411BE43F8BC1F
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/selmf/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_kirillshkrogalev_ffmpeg-next_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_kirillshkrogalev_ffmpeg-next_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

Any idea how to fix this, I followed several links like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769925/ubuntu-16-04-sudo-apt-get-update-error), [this](https://www.techbrown.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu-16-04/) and more. but nothing fix it.

here is the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

Comment: unchecking the repos that have errors solved my problem

System Settings > Software and Updates > Other Software